# Get text of WebElement which contains html tags

Tags: java, javascript, html, selenium

How can I get the Inner HTML of a `WebElement` with Selenium?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
WebElement divData=driver.findElement(By.id("data"));  
divData.getText();  //returns empty   
OR  
divData.getAttribute("innerHTML"); //returns empty  
OR  
String script="return arguments[0].innerHTML";  
String result=(String) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(script,divData);

System.out.println(""+result); //empty
```

Comment: <div id="data">
   <b>hello</b><br>
    "This is school"<br>
</div>

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: fetching the div's content

Comment: @GrishmaOswal Are you sure `#data` exists. Does `#data` *have any* HTML? Can you show the markup you're running this against?

Comment: Are you using the webdriver?

Comment: print out the "WebElement divData=driver.findElement(By.id("data")); " result, please

Comment: [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (0a79463410aff2f466706295f32d4ec5)] -> id: data]

Comment: Could you add your entire code here .. it would be easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

as I see from the comment
{quote}

**hello**
 "This is school"

{quote}

Representing the above in a tree view: 
[image: tree view of HTML]

So basic webdriver method  `WebElement.getText()`     should work for any properly located element which contains the text.

So there 2 possbilities to find the text of webelement:

- I)   try get text from all sublements (childs) related to the div above:

  ```
  List<WebElement> childsOfDiv =driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(#data>*));

  for(WebElement iter: childsOfDiv){
      System.out.println(iter.getText());
  }
  ```
- II)
  get elements' text by js method involving `javascriptexecutor`
  Initial step is to find locators of child elements related to div:

  ```
  String child1CSS="#data>b";
  String child2CSS="#data>br";

  public String getTextInvolvingJs(String cssLocator)
  {
   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
   StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

   stringBuilder.append("var x = $(\""+cssLocator+"\");");
   stringBuilder.append("return x.text().toString();")       ;

   String res= (String) js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
   return res;

  }

  String foundText1= getTextInvolvingJs(child1CSS);
  String foundText2= getTextInvolvingJs(child2CSS);
  ```

Hope this  works for you.